# org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne references an unknown entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 microservices on postgresql - Account and Employee. Where Account is dependent on Employee.
I'm stuck for a few days with this problem:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.rszumlas.account.Account.employee references an unknown entity: com.rszumlas.employee.Employee
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at com.rszumlas.account.AccountApplication.main(AccountApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.rszumlas.account.Account.employee references an unknown entity: com.rszumlas.employee.Employee
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1750) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1694) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1623) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 16 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Account entity:**

```
package com.rszumlas.account;

import com.rszumlas.employee.Employee;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.SEQUENCE;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "Account")
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "account_sequence",
            sequenceName = "account_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = SEQUENCE,
            generator = "account_sequence"
    )
    @Column(
            name = "id",
            updatable = false
    )
    private Long id;

    @Column(
            name = "email",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String email;

    @Column(
            name = "password",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "employee_id",
            referencedColumnName = "id",
            nullable = false,
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
                    name = "account_employee_id_fk"
            )
    )
    private Employee employee;

}
```

**Employee entity:**

```
package com.rszumlas.employee;


import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.SEQUENCE;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "Employee")
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "order_type_sequence",
            sequenceName = "order_type_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = SEQUENCE,
            generator = "order_type_sequence"
    )
    @Column(
            name = "id",
            updatable = false
    )
    private Long id;

    @Column(
            name = "first_name",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String first_name;

    @Column(
            name = "last_name",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String last_name;

    @Column(
            name = "eth",
            nullable = false
    )
    private double eth;

    @Column(
            name = "PESEL",
            nullable = false
    )
    private int PESEL;

}
```

**Parent pom.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
      <groupId>com.rszumlas.ethanol</groupId>
      <artifactId>ethanol</artifactId>
      <packaging>pom</packaging>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <modules>
        <module>vodka</module>
        <module>shelf</module>
        <module>employee</module>
        <module>account</module>
        <module>order</module>
        <module>order-accepted</module>
        <module>order-done</module>
        <module>order-handling-info</module>
        <module>clients</module>
      </modules>
    
      <name>ethanol</name>
      <url>http://www.example.com</url>
    
      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
      </properties>
    
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
          <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
          <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
          <version>42.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
          <optional>true</optional>
          <version>1.18.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
          <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
          <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.13.2</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
          <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
          <version>3.29.2-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    
      <build>
    
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
          <plugins>
            <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
      </build>
    </project>
```

The same problem also occurs in any relations between other microservices.
Don't really see any typo, just following some tutorial on Spring Data JPA.

Thought a missing employee table in postgresql database is a problem, but it isn't. I created it, and still it throws exception.

Comment: I hate Spring's dynamic persistence units; I don't know the config well, but I suspect you haven't set it up so that the employee and address packages are not picked up in the same persistence unit. Try putting them in the same package, and verify with the tutorials how they have setup the persistence units and the Classes with in them - they usually do more than just mark a class with the @Entity annotation, giving it a way to limit the packages it scans for entities.

Comment: Have you checked hibernate configuration, especially the mapping config?